Google Photo in an html page
I uploaded a photo on Google Photo. Created a shared link from the album. I want to display the image in an html page.
Following is the code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Photo from Google Photos</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>My Photo from Google Photos</h1>
    <img src="https://photos.app.goo.gl/p5zKANtqKhoqdM9q8" alt="Test Photo">
</body>
</html>

The image is not displayed. Has the link not been shared publicly? If not, how to do it, so that the image url can be used in html code.

It seems, images from Google Photos cannot be used in an HTML page. Here is the link.
